# XDG0062 Failed to retrieve the child at index 0

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, winui, winui-3

I have spent around 7 hours trying to get WinUI to work with in my UWP POC. At this point I need any help that I can get I have spent hours going through all of microsofts pages on installing WinUI but have gotten absolutely nowhere. With the project that I working on I would love to have some of the controls that WinUI adds to UWP. I downloaded the XamlControlsGallery from microsoft to see what all is available for UWP and I love what is out there. What I dont like is how much time I have spent on trying to implement this in to my UWP POC. Sometimes I can get the application to start but all I get is a splash screen and the it gives me what is shown in the second picture. Any help would greatly be appreciated here is a screenshot of the error that I am getting.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of WinUI are you using, WinUI-2.6 or WinUI-3? Could you please tell me if you had followed any tutorials? If not, would you mind take a look at this document: [Getting started with the Windows UI 2 Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started)?

Comment: So I have been trying to use either or to my understanding both WinUI 2 and 3 should work with UWP applications. As of tutorials I have gone through : these 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started   

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/   

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/   

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment    

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app?tabs=desktop-csharp

Comment: So which version did you use in your app now indeed? Another thing is that have you tired a new blank app to see if you could make the app run correctly?

Comment: So my minimum target version has to 2004 for our security polices, yes I have tried making a completely new blank project and trying to put the WinUI into that project. I still get the same sort of errors that show up there as well.

Comment: Well, I want to know the WinUI version that you used in your app indeed.

Comment: But this is an interesting behavior, I created a blank project (min target 2004) and added the latest WInUI-2.7. It still works correctly. Maybe you could share the blank app sample on Github or OneDrive so that I could check that. Please note that a blank project that could reproduce this will be enough.

Comment: So for some reason it just magically started working.... I have no idea dude, but thank you for all the help you provided me! @RoyLi-MSFT